# Exporting a UI data to the Server Side using Angular2 typescript

Tags: json, angular, typescript, export-to-csv

I have a table in the UI with the data. I want to export that data to the api side( restful service) in the csv format ( or json format, later I can convert that to the csv format on server side)   so that I can download the file to provide a report. 
I have a data as below as in the attachment:

I want all the table data to to be stored in an object and pass that object to the service side as a URL(using a POST request).

And I need to download that data on the server side( For this I have written a code to convert a JSON data to CSV form and then exporting it )

Have google for it and all I came across is the .js files and functions for it.while I am using/need typescript.

can I get a code snippet for it or at-least how to approach for a solution.

thanks in advance for the response.

Answer (score 0):

You can export data (assuming that you have the list of data ) as Json object using http module, here the code that should do the work:

```
exportData(dataList : any): Observable<any> {
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }); 
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        return this.http.post(this.serverApiUrl, JSON.stringify(dataList), options)
          .map(res => {
            return res.json();
          });
      }
```